# How to get details of DownloadError?

Tags: google-app-engine, error-handling, urlfetch

I do the following:

```
try:
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=some_url, 
    ...
except DownloadError:
    self.response.out.write('DownloadError')
    logging.error('DownloadError')                                            
except Error:
    self.response.out.write('Error')
    logging.error('Error')
```

Is there any way to get some more detailed description on what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `logging.exception` to add the Exception to the ERROR logging message:

```
try:
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=some_url, 
    ...
except DownloadError, exception:
    self.response.out.write('Oops, DownloadError: %s' % exception)
    logging.exception('DownloadError')                                         
except Error:
    self.response.out.write('Oops, Error')
    logging.exception('Error')
```

Comment: Whilst this is certainly good practice, in this instance, it won't add anything meaningful.  The GAE does not give you any more info on DownloadError.

Comment: @Jan of course logging.exception gives the stacktrace for DownloadError exception; downvoting seems a little bit inopportune here.

Comment: It gives text description of the error - `DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 The connect operation timed out`. Can I get it somehow to display on the page?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  A download error is usually a timeout in our experience - something on the back end taking too long to respond (first byte).  If it is receiving data, it looks like GAE will wait and throw a Deadline exception instead after your 10 seconds is up.

Does it *ever* succeed? Your choices on how to deal with d/l exceptions will vary depending on the back-end.

If you're taking the simplistic route and just retrying, beware of quotas and limiters - chances are your requests are indeed reaching the other system, and just aren't coming back in time.  Very easy to blow past limiters this way.

J